マクロを使用してPDFを作成した時に取り消し線が付くようになった
マクロを使用してPDFを作成しているですが、PDFを確認すると日付に取り消し線が付くようになりました。
書式設定やマクロも確認しましたが、取り消し線が付く理由が分かりません。
PDF作成後にExcelデータを確認しても取り消し線は表示されていませんでした。
「ファイル」→「エクスポート」→「PDF/XPSドキュメントの作成」と手作業で行うと日付に取り消し線は付かなかったため、マクロでの解消方法を教えてほしいです。
※追記
日付のセルに関数を使用していたのですが、関数を抜いてみたところ、取消し線が付くことなくPDF化できました。
関数を入力したままでもPDF化できるようにしたいです。
※追記2
Excelのバージョン： Microsoft 365 MSO (バージョン 2410 ビルド 16.0.18129.20158) 64 ビット
※マクロのコード
Sub macro001()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Cursor = xlWait
    
    Dim startTime As Single
    Dim endTime As Single
    Dim processTime As Integer
     
    '開始時間取得
    startTime = Timer

'----------------------ここから内容

Set wsControl = Sheets("Control")
Set wsSource = Sheets("Source")
Set wsPrint = Sheets("Print")

er1 = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To er1

    wsPrint.Cells(4, 2) = wsSource.Cells(i, 5)  '社名
    wsPrint.Cells(5, 6) = wsSource.Cells(i, 4)  '顧客番号

        
        wsPrint.Cells(22, 9) = wsSource.Cells(i, 9)  'キー1
        wsPrint.Cells(22, 19) = wsSource.Cells(i, 7)  'キー1金額
        wsPrint.Cells(23, 9) = ""  '空白
        wsPrint.Cells(23, 19) = ""  '空白
        

    Dim fileName As String '保存先フォルダパス＆ファイル名
    myPath = wsControl.Cells(8, 2)
    fileName = myPath & "\" & wsPrint.Cells(5, 6) & "_" & wsPrint.Cells(4, 2) & ".pdf"
   
    wsPrint.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fileName

Next i

'################## 処理開始 ##################



'----------------------ここまで内容
    
    '終了時間取得
    endTime = Timer
     
    '処理時間計算
    processTime = endTime - startTime
    
    MsgBox ("処理は" & processTime & "秒で完了しました。")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    
    Exit Sub


End Sub


「取り消し線が付くようになった」ということは以前は付かなかったということですよね？全く同じエクセルファイルとマクロのコードで結果が以前とは異なるということですか？

@merino　仰る通りです。

Microsoft Community での下記の質問の abecmin さんの回答は試しましたか？
「マクロを使用してPDFを作成した時に取り消し線が付くようになった」　　
https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum/all/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF/9fe047f5-18a4-4d62-8106-fe530c81b1b1

@motosannさん 　abecminさんの回答を見落としておりました､､。「PDFの印刷動作を行う前に計算方法を自動に戻すなどマクロを修正してみてください。」→このとおり、自動計算に戻したところ、取消し線が付くことなくPDFの作成ができるようになりました。ご連絡いただきありがとうございました。

解決した場合にはコメント欄で終わらせず、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。 (当サイトでは自己回答も歓迎されます)

https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum/all/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF/9fe047f5-18a4-4d62-8106-fe530c81b1b1

Excelのバージョンは365ですか?
またマクロの処理の一連で計算方法を自動以外 (Application.Calculation = >xlCalculationManual など) にして、そのあとにPDF作成していませんか?
最近の仕様変更で計算方法が手動、再計算が行われていないセルには取り消し線が表示されるようにな>りました。
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/microsoft365insiderblog/stale-value-formatting-now-available-in-excel-for-windows/4281372
https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/%E5%8F%A4%E3%81%84%E5%80%A4%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B8%E5%BC%8F%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A-4b5c63c3-5dc7-4e9b-8e24-88bed1987dbd
PDFの印刷動作を行う前に計算方法を自動に戻すなどマクロを修正してみてください。


同じURLがコメントされています。また、他サイトからの引用のみという回答は少々乱暴です。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer をお読みいただき、良い回答になるよう心がけてみてください。
